# Unusual chord progression

Tags: harmony, chord-progressions

I'm beginning my harmony studies, and I'm using some pop music to practice.

I started to analyse a tune from Spice Girls: "Say You'll Be There". Its tone is `D major`, so the verses feature this chord progression:

```
    vi II IV  I
    Bm E  G   D
```

**First attention point:** the second degree is major, not minor as usual. I do see this type of harmonization before, but don't understand it fully yet.

What really puzzles me is the chord progression of the bridge:

```
    V vi  IV  V
    C Bm  Bb  A
```

It suggests a modulation to `F major`, but the chords `Bm` and `A` don't belong to that tonality. It seems to me this bridge alternates between `D major` and `F major` in its chord progression, what is very unusual, at least for my studies so far.

Like I said, I'm a beginner practitioner and I might miss something. What could it be?

Comment: When you progress past being a beginner, you will discover that "the scale of a key contains 7 notes" is just a simplified idea to get you started. Any key contains all 12 notes, and all 24 major and minor chords (not to mention other chord types!) - it's just that some of the notes and chords get used more often than others. And IMO "tonality" is like "pornography" - you can't define exactly what tonality is, but you know it when you hear it. (And FWIW J S Bach wrote plenty of chord progressions that are far more "way out" than the two you quoted from the Spice Girls!)

Comment: You're right. The chord progression templates are by no means rigid. What I'm trying to understand are the relations and functions the chords of the song's bridge are performing.

Comment: In your second chord progression, given that C is V and Bb is IV, Bm must be ♮iv, not vi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a preface, I know the song you're talking about and those aren't quite the chords. I haven't heard it in at least a decade, but I'm going to use the chords that I believe to be correct in my answer.

There are two general concepts about harmony that are important to understand when looking at progressions that mix chords from the key and chords not from the key:

1. Chords from outside the key are overwhelmingly common and do not represent a breaking of the rules but an adaptation of them; indeed, when looking at borrowed chords, generally what defines them is their relationship to the "original" key.
2. Chromatic basslines are also very common and, because they can't occur in a diatonic system by definition*, they necessarily invoke lots of borrowing.

Let's look at the first progression first because it's easier.

```
BMi | E      | G  (Gmi) | D  (D/C#) |
 vi   V-of-V   IV (iv)    I  (I/VII)
```

There's only one standout label here, and it's on the E. In the key of D, E would typically be called V-of-V; it is the chord on the fifth of the key... of the chord on the fifth of the key. This is termed a **secondary dominant**. Secondary dominants are a relatively advanced concept (particularly if you're not comfortable with what a primary dominant is; if that's the case, I'd investigate that further before looking at secondary dominants). Nonetheless, a brief summary of their purpose is to provide a temporary suggestion of another key: V-of-V suggests V; V-of-IV suggests IV, V-of-vi suggests vi... and so on.

Generally, V-of-V is followed by V, but fairly often it is followed by IV instead. The reasons for this aren't so simple, but basically what it comes down to is the fact that Bmi-E strongly suggests the dorian mode on B (which comes from A major) and then the G quickly pulls you back to the D major system. This is a fairly common chord progression in pop music because it gives you access to a lot of notes while leaving you grounded in familiar territory.

I've also added a Gmi and D/C# in brackets. This is because the chorus almost certainly uses the minor chord on the fourth, at least some of the time, and the bass line that I remember has a pretty fat C# in it. Functionally, these don't change much, but it's worth noting that iv is another very common borrowing and is perhaps the most prominent example of a concept called **modal interchange**, where chords from parallel scales are used.

Now, the second progression:

```
C        | G/B  | Bb | A7
bVII       IV/vi bVI   V7
(IV-of-IV) (IV)
```

N.B.: You have this labelled as a bridge, but I'm fairly certain this is a pre-chorus.

This is a chromatically descending bassline. It attempts to get us to the dominant chord in four bars, and so it starts three semitones above the intended root and moves the root down a semitone until it gets to the ending point. At a high level, this is how chromatic basslines work: The chromaticism of the bassline is the anchor. There are few things more common in contemporary music than the chromatic bassline, and to explain all of the possible variations and their differences would require an exceedingly large block of text.

But back to the Spice Girls. The first chord is C; this is another example of **modal interchange** and it comes from the mixolydian mode. The chord that generally follows the bVII is the IV, and that's what we've got here. The Bb is also an example of modal interchange, but this time we're borrowing from minor; it gives us access to F as a melody note and serves the purpose of moving the bassline one semitone closer to A. The last chord is the dominant chord of our key and serves as an ideal transition back to a tonic chord (in this case B minor).

An important note of distinction here is that at no point in time have we actually modulated to a different key. We've suggested a lot of different scales, but with the exception of E (which, as a secondary dominant, is an example of *tonicization*) the key we've suggested has always had a tonic of D.

A little disclaimer about my transcription: I didn't actually listen to the song when I came up with these changes and I haven't heard the song for many years. Nevertheless, the only chord that can actually be "wrong" here is G/B, and what you may find that the bass is actually playing a G, not a B. This doesn't affect the overall analysis too much, however, as it simply means that the descending chromatic line is in the melody, not the bass. I will verify one way or another later today.

*Diatonic systems contain one of each letter name; this quickly becomes impossible to maintain with a chromatic bassline.

Answer (score 0):

I listened to the song now and the key is Bb minor (I suppose you transcribed it in Bm to be easier? )

anyway, the verses use : a progression of 2 chords that can be seen built on a Dorian scale (or a simple chromatic alteration of a chord built on 4th step of the minor scale, a "borrowed " chord) - after that, I hear the same chord that changes from Major to minor (it's got a similar sound to the progression that you wrote) and at the end , the final chord of these four chords is a Major and it sounds like a new tonic in the relative Major (it is the same tonal area, and more or less the same notes)

that cool, 70s and Soul-oriented pre chorus (or bridge) is made of quartal chords , especially

I hear : Db 7/4  that brings to Gb Major 7th   - in your transcription, it will be:  C 7/4 , F Maj7 - not Bm (are you sure??)

and these 2 chords are part of one tonality (call it tonal "area" if you like)

- if you listen to the melody that they sing, they sing the Major 7th, when the Maj 7 chord occurs
- after that, there's a key switch ( a "tonal center" change) and, in my transcription, I hear a 7/4 chord that is a B 7/4  and it's exactly one whole step lower than the first one of the pre chorus

In your key , it will be :    C 7/4,  F Maj7,    Bb 7/4 ....

and it goes directly to the last 7/4 of the series, which in my key is Ab 7/4  and in your key is A (7/4)

If you listen to ,,,,say Michael Jackson of the first album, or Stevie Wonder in the 70s,,, these harmonies were common , Spice Girls used some good song writer here...

Comment: Listening to the version I found on YouTube, this tune is clearly in D♭ major, not B♭ minor. [Wikipedia agrees with me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Say_You'll_Be_There#Composition).

Comment: ah wikipedia agrees with you? and who cares- B b minor with a Dorian variation, thats all-

Comment: Well, agree that who cares if Wikipedia agrees, but the key is clearly D♭ major, not B♭ minor. These two keys are not the same.

Comment: I suppose that you are not familiar with modes, right? B b minor (Dorian) is exactly in the same key of Db- it's exactly the same thing- the song starts with a B b minor and follows a mixed mode composition technique- the second chord is built on the IV step of B b minor (Dorian progression) and, using a plagal (IV-I) cadenza, it resolves in Db Major- Happy now?

Comment: Ignoring your obnoxious condescension, modes are not keys. You said key of B♭ minor. The first chord is a B♭ minor, but this is not the key. The key is D♭ major. No need to appeal to "mixed mode composition technique" to determine the tonality here.

Comment: I did not say that modes are not scales, I said that they are not keys. The key of D♭ major has tonal center D♭, while the key of B♭ minor has tonal center B♭.

Comment: Anyway, I think that the problem is based on different kinds of music analysys, I feel the tonic chord is the B b minor (with a dorian relationship/ variation on the chord that follows) and of course, yes, it transforms into Db Major.  It' the same tonal area - it only needs a view that is not classical

Comment: Please, now do a little experiment and play the second chord: it's an Eb Major , right ? A chord that does not exist in the key of Db (I'm sure you know it would be minor) - since here we're not talking of "secondary dominants" - because the Eb is not moving towards a momentary tonic...it's clear that it's about mixed modes, Eb Major would be a chord built with a Db Lydian scale - I agree that the key is Db Major, but it's got variations -that I see coming from a modal harmony approach, but one can analyze it from another point of view

Comment: Yes, E♭ Maj is not a chord diatonic to D♭ major (it actually sounds like an E♭7). I agree that it's fine to talk about this as mixing modes or borrowing chords or whatever, but this doesn't change the key center of the song. To me it feels like the chords are all moving towards the D♭ Maj chord. It feels like you could view the B♭ min - E♭ Maj as ii - V7 in A♭, then G♭ Maj - D♭ Maj as IV - I in D♭.

Comment: OK, then...it's in Db ! I agree that you can also view it in Db Major, with the second "diatonic" chord (Eb) with a chromatic alteration, if you like it...

Comment: I also think that the problem here was which analyzing method is more correct, being a modern song...but to me, if I think about the progression, it could have been written by Bach, it's not so "modern" after all,,,the best is when the pre-chorus comes in, with all those 7/4 chords...what do you think about the pre chorus ?

Comment: Those changes in the pre-chorus are nice. I'm not sure that I am hearing them the same way as you. I hear **BMaj7 - B♭min - AMaj7 - A♭(sus4)**. I can't tell if there is a resolution to **A♭** in there or not, the mix seems to be hiding that from me (and I am listening on a laptop right now). I am not exactly sure what you mean by, e.g. **B 7/4** above. Is that a seventh chord with the 4th in the bass? In any case, the only sus chord I am hearing is the final **A♭**, but I could be missing something here. This is undoubtedly the most time I have ever spent listening to Spice Girls ;)

Comment: me too, me too...lol...I think the video on Youtube has something strange relating to the frequencies (my guitar is 440 Hz but the video, who knows?) - Anyway, I 'm listening again and the pre chorus seem to open the sequence with a Bass in B (I thought the chord was a 7/4 because playing it on my guitar it sounded very cool and seventies (Wonder, Jackson, and so on)... so it would have been a B/Db , on guitar, a quartal chord. That bass resolves on a "momentary" tonic (Gb Maj7) , then the following chord seems to be a B 7/4 with the Bass in B -even if it's not clear , frequencies are too bass

Comment: I thought about that chord (Gb Maj 7 ) coz at that moment I feel a sense of "tranquillity,serenity" that is the characteristic of those delta chords, of course, I 'm not sure 100% , I wish I had the original CD- Now I'm listening to Spice Girls "Say You'll Be There" (Spice World Version...) as well, I hope it's better, I also spotted a dim chord somewhere...

Answer (score -1):

Related to the bridge: is this the real chord sequence as played on the record or does this come from a simplified score ? 
if the Bb in the bridge is a Bb7 we might have a tritone substitution from E7 to Bb7 leading to the A chord.  This is a development of a ii - V7 - I sequence as often used in jazz (originally Bm - E7 - A) including in situations where the composer uses secondary dominants